# Ajax is sending data but Php file is not recieving it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've spent the past 10 or so days trying to fix this to some success but I'm still stuck. I'm making an online budgeting system which takes Javascript values, sends them via Ajax to PHP where they are then sent to a database. Here is my code for javascript

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'yup.php',
   type:'post',
   data:{
          'Sal': Sal,
          'TaxReb': TaxReb,
          'RetInv': RetInv,
          'IntSave': IntSave,
          'Pen': Pen,
          'Dividends': Dividends,
          'Wages':Wages,
          'Loans':Loans,
          'Benefits':Benefits,
          'IncOther': IncOther,
          'Tax': Tax ,
          'Groc': Groc ,
          'Take':Take ,
          'Rent': Rent ,
          'Elec': Elec ,
          'Trans': Trans ,
          'Mort': Mort ,
          'LoanPay':LoanPay ,
          'Goods': Goods ,
          'ExpOther': ExpOther ,
          'TotalInc':TotalInc ,
          'TotalExp': TotalExp ,
          'NetInc':NetInc
    },

    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        window.location.href='yup.php';
    }
});
```

The values are integers which are working on the Jscript file. The alert gives me this message:

```
Array(
[Sal] => 33245
[TaxReb] => 324523
[RetInv] => 3245
[IntSave] => 2345
[Pen] => 3524
[Dividends] => 5342
[Wages] => 35425342
[Loans] => 5432
[Benefits] => 254325
[IncOther] => 4352
[Tax] => 34
[Groc] => 3434
[Take] => 34
[Rent] => 34
[Elec] => 34
[Trans] => 34
[Mort] => 34
[LoanPay] => 34
[Goods] => 34
[ExpOther] => 34
[TotalInc] => 36061675
[TotalExp] => 3740
[NetInc] => 36057935
)`
```

My PHP code is this:

```
<?php header(' charset=utf-8');
print_r($_POST)
//$Sal=$_POST['Sal'];
//echo $Sal;
```

However on my PHP page it gives me this:
Array ( ) 
And when I uncomment the variables it gives me the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: Sal in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\yup.php on line 2

I removed the `print_r` when trying to get the actual variable.
When I use **server request method** the alert says *post* whereas the php page says *get*. This might be part of the problem but I have no idea how to fix it and neither did the other pages I looked at on this or other websites. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the path  url: 'yup.php' is correct? Did you try using the full path there?

Comment: The redirect will initialize a new instance of `yup.php` without all the post data. Sounds like you don't need ajax for this at all and just want to submit this as a form, or you need to store the ajax data in session variable

Comment: If you're making an AJAX request with POST data to `yup.php`, why are you then redirecting to `yup.php` (through a GET request with no data) immediately after the request anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making two separate requests to `yup.php`. There is the POST request made using AJAX and there is the GET request made when you redirect the user to `yup.php` in the `success()` function. The GET request, which is what is sending information back to the user to display on the page, doesn't receive the information from the AJAX request because, well, you didn't send the server any information in the GET request. You previously made a separate POST request to `yup.php` which did receive the data and proceeded to run your script (i.e. print out the information).

If your goal is to present the user some response from the server after submitting the AJAX request, then you should use the `data` argument in your `success()` function to do so. What you've done with the `alert()` is one way to present the data, though likely unsatisfactory. What you likely want to do is use JavaScript to insert that data somewhere into the current page.

The crucial point to understand here is that you are making two separate requests to `yup.php`, only one of which receives the data you sent using AJAX.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realise this was the case.